# AWS S3 upload via signed url

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to let users to upload files directly to S3 using signed url. I use node js aws-sdk to create this url:

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
var config = require('../../server/config.json');
aws.config = config.aws;

const s3 = new aws.S3();
const s3Params = {
  Bucket: config.aws.bucket,
  Key: instance.filename,
  Expires: 60,
  ACL: 'public-read'
};

s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', s3Params, (err, signedUrl) => {
  if(err){
    return next(err);
  }
  instance.uploadUrl = signedUrl;
  next();
});
```

So I've got signed URL

Request URL:https://f.workdoer.com.s3.amazonaws.com/IMG_4875.PNG.png?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIFVWPIVVIGIONPXA&Expires=1502381111&Signature=Af9meXlMA7qj5HYALs7LzhWaftc%3D&x-amz-acl=public-read

```
Request headers:
PUT /IMG_4875.PNG.png?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIFVWPIVVIGIONPXA&Expires=1502381111&Signature=Af9meXlMA7qj5HYALs7LzhWaftc%3D&x-amz-acl=public-read HTTP/1.1
Host: f.workdoer.com.s3.amazonaws.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 130838
Accept: application/json,text/javascript
Origin: http://localhost:4200
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarygDui83iohothuh7E
Referer: http://localhost:4200/app/team/1/project/15/list/task/2074
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: ru,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6,uk;q=0.4,it;q=0.2,de;q=0.2

Request Payload:
------WebKitFormBoundarygDui83iohothuh7E
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Content-Type"

image/png
------WebKitFormBoundarygDui83iohothuh7E
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="IMG_4875.PNG.png"
Content-Type: image/png


------WebKitFormBoundarygDui83iohothuh7E--
```

And I've got from Amazon:

```
<Error><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message><AWSAccessKeyId>AKIAIFVWPIVVIGIONPXA</AWSAccessKeyId><StringToSign>PUT

multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarygDui83iohothuh7E
1502381111
x-amz-acl:public-read
/f.workdoer.com/IMG_4875.PNG.png</StringToSign><SignatureProvided>Af9meXlMA7qj5HYALs7LzhWaftc=</SignatureProvided>
```

Something wrong with the request, because when I put it with CURL:

```
curl -k -X PUT -T "IMG_4875.PNG.png" "https://f.workdoer.com.s3.amazonaws.com/IMG_4875.PNG.png?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIFVWPIVVIGIONPXA&Expires=1502381111&Signature=Af9meXlMA7qj5HYALs7LzhWaftc%3D&x-amz-acl=public-read"
```

it's successfully uploaded. What I'm doing wrong?

Here is my bucket policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Allow Public Access to All Objects",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::f.workdoer.com/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

And cors:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <ExposeHeader>Location</ExposeHeader>
    <AllowedHeader>Content-Type</AllowedHeader>
    <AllowedHeader>x-amz-acl</AllowedHeader>
    <AllowedHeader>origin</AllowedHeader>
    <AllowedHeader>accept</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Just to be sure: Are you doing both calls from the same machine? If not, a wrong clock could be the problem.

Comment: Yes, on same machine during 10 seconds

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41078440/signaturedoesnotmatch-error-when-uploading-to-s3-via-a-pre-signed-url-using-ioni sounds like it could be the same problem as yours.

Comment: Thanks! But I've tried to set content type. Same result. Seems like it form post, so I have to sign in other way.

Comment: Not a duplicate of the other question.  This is also not CORS and not policy related.  What you're doing wrong, here, among other things, is that you are using `multipart/form-data` for a `PUT`.  S3 expects raw data for a `PUT` -- just the octets of the object itself, not a form structure around it.